# generating a table onto html with .innerHTML from 2d arraylist javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to innerHTML the table with a 2d arraylist, but it seems like i am only getting the table as 1 column, all cells stacked on top of one another.
Could you guys see what I did to do this, and see how to resolve this? Thank you

```
for(var i = 0; i < transposedList.length; i++) {
    tablehere.innerHTML += '<tr>';
    for(var j = 0; j < transposedList[i].length; j++) {
        tablehere.innerHTML += '<td>' + transposedList[i][j] + '</td>';
    }tablehere.innerHTML += '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: The issue is that you are treating `innerHTML` as if it is just a string.  It is not.  When you do `innerHTML += '<tr>'` that single statement is going to cause the DOM to create a complete TR element.  It does not wait for the `</tr>` to be appended.  It has no idea that you will ever do that.  To fix your issue, append all this html to a temporary string variable, and assign that to the innerHTML at the end.

Comment: @Taplar I see, thank you for your insight! It really helped!